# Need help with installing problem

Tags: system-installation

I've been trying to install ubuntu in virtualbox for the past couple of hours, but always, in the screen that is supposed to say "install ubuntu" or "try ubuntu without installing" I get this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you get that garbled screen, do this:

Switch back and forth to the tty7 (**ctrl+alt+F1** and then **ctrl+alt+F7**) fixes the display.

Then you can install or try Ubuntu successfully.

Cheers, Al